# Make Div overlay ENTIRE page (not just viewport)?

Tags: html, css

So I have a problem that I think is quite common but I have yet to find a good solution for.  I want to make an overlay div cover the ENTIRE page... NOT just the viewport.  I don't understand why this is so hard to do...  I've tried setting body, html heights to 100% etc but that isn't working.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .OverLay { position: absolute; z-index: 3; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50); top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: Black; color: White;}
    body { height: 100%; }
    html { height: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 300px; background-color: Red;">
        </div>
        <div style="height: 230px; width: 9000px; background-color: Green;">
        </div>
        <div style="height: 900px; width: 200px; background-color: Blue;"></div>
        <div class="OverLay">TestTest!</div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

I'd also be open to a solution in JavaScript if one exists, but I'd much rather just be using some simple CSS.

Comment: Can read also more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938536/how-to-make-the-height-really-100/1938592#1938592

Comment: Can this be done for real with jQuery?

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The viewport is all that matters, but you likely want the entire website to stay darkened even while scrolling. For this, you want to use `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`. Fixed will keep the element static on the screen as you scroll, giving the impression that the entire body is darkened.

Example: http://jsbin.com/okabo3/edit

```
div.fadeMe {
  opacity:    0.5; 
  background: #000; 
  width:      100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    10;
  top:        0; 
  left:       0; 
  position:   fixed; 
}
```

```
<body>
  <div class="fadeMe"></div>
  <p>A bunch of content here...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but will position fixed work in IE6?! I know probably nobody cares much about IE6 anymore.

Comment: @Marco Not sure. To be honest, if support for a browser 10 year old isn't explicitly requested, I'm not going to bother anymore :)

Comment: So how do you guys do it on mobile devices? http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: +1 Thanks! I extended your example by adding a popup window above the overlay: http://jsbin.com/okabo3/740/

Comment: the issue i'm having with this (which is used by many a plug in) is when you click a `<select>` element in iOS it moves the entire viewport and basically breaks everything.  fixed elements move, things that shouldn't scroll scroll, etc.

Comment: If you use `position: fixed` make sure to test on small screens because you get problems if the overlay content is larger than the screen/window.

Answer (score 18):

```
body:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: The best possible solution out there. You just toggle "overlayed" class for body and apply the styling above to the body with that className.

Comment: Please explain this answer more. I don't understand Sviatoslav's comment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you've misunderstood what the viewport is. The viewport is the area a browser uses to render web pages, and you cannot in any way build your web sites to override this area in any way.

Secondly, it seems that the reason that your overlay-div won't cover *the entire viewport* is because you have to remove all margins on BODY and HTML.

Try adding this at the top of your stylesheet - it resets all margins and paddings on all elements. Makes further development easier:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

*Edit:
I just understood your question better.* `Position: fixed;` *will probably work out for you, as Jonathan Sampson have written.*

Comment: You shouldn't removing padding and margins from *everything*. It could be really laborious to get those back for many elements like buttons and form inputs.

Comment: In my opinion, its just a really easy way to treat everything more as the same across browsers. Might not apply as much today as it did back before when adapting to IE5, but I still do it as one of the first things i write in a stylesheet.

Comment: @Arve It gets you close, but it's better to use a time-tested reset sheet instead. Check out http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ for more information - you'll love it, I assure you :)

Comment: I've seen it, and I simply think it's too big :)

Comment: @Arve The resets aren't that big - try recovering completely from `*{}` and you'll see a lot more :)

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a bit of trouble as I didn't want to FIX the overlay in place as I wanted the info inside the overlay to be scrollable over the text. I used:

```
<html style="height=100%">
   <body style="position:relative">
      <div id="my-awesome-overlay" 
           style="position:absolute; 
                  height:100%; 
                  width:100%; 
                  display: block">
           [epic content here]
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Of course the div in the middle needs some content and probably a transparent grey background but I'm sure you get the gist!

Answer (score -7):

I looked at Nate Barr's answer above, which you seemed to like. It doesn't seem very different from the simpler

```
html {background-color: grey}
```