# Cover whole html page in grey to indicate temporary disablement

Tags: javascript, html, css

For my html page I would like to be able to shade the whole page to indicate temporary disablement of all items in the page, the way it is when (for example) when one opens the "Insert Image" dialog box in the "Ask question" section here (as shown in the snapshot below).

The only thing I can think of is setting the page’s bgcolor attribute to grey, but that's not quite what I want because the shading should appear on top of the page items, not behind them. What is the correct way to do it ?

[image]

Comment: you just make a huge div with fixed position and big z-index that covers the screen

Comment: `.overall-div { position: fixed; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0 }`

Comment: Using `Cover whole html page in grey` as search phrase (in google) will show [Make Div overlay ENTIRE page (not just viewport)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852276/make-div-overlay-entire-page-not-just-viewport) on the first page as result

Comment: have you tried some of the proposed solution?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan Not yet ... but that's a strange question. Why do you ask ?

Comment: I ask you just because I'd like to know if you solved the problem or if there's something else. it is called  "empathy" :)

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan oh all right, thanks for your empathy then ... in case you’re anxious about getting your answer accepted, I inform you that I prefer to accept an answer only when I have tested it a lot, rather than accept quickly and then disappoint people by unaccepting it much later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply a `disabled` class to your body and define this style

```
body.disabled:before {
   content: "";
   position: fixed;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: ... /* choose a z-index so that no other element can overlap it */
   background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);  
}
```

Example

```css
body.disabled:before {
   content: "";
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1;
   min-height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);  
}


.popup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px #ccc solid;
  padding: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}
```

```html
<body class="disabled">
  I'm the body
  
  <div class="popup">I'm the popup</div> 
</body>
```

If you use a pseudolement you won't need to use empty markup only for styling purpose.
When the user interaction has completed, just remove the `disabled` class (via js)

Comment: How do I add the popup, nonshaded element to your Codepen example ? I tried just about everywhere and it was shaded along with the rest. May I also ask what's the point of the "before" after your body.disabled ? The script seems to work the same without it.

Comment: I updated the example with a popup. the point of the pseudoelement is to apply some style not to the body, but instead on a layer that overlaps the body itself. From a visual point of view the basic effect is the same, but what if your body has already a background applied? Another difference is when your body has a scrollbar. If you apply that class on body the scrollbar disappears and the page "jumps" on top

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer. I think I begin to understand : anything not in the "disabled" class will appear unshaded

Comment: you're welcome. if you need other clarification just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a div over the rest of your page

```
<div id="overlay"></div>


#overlay{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:[what ever you want]
}
```

N.b. however I prefer the :before option (assuming you don't need legacy IE support)