# How to block entire React UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, subscription, featuretoggle

What is the best way to block the ui, when, let's say, a subscription ends?
The notification that the subscription ends comes from the back end. But what then? Set a flag in every component whether it is rendered or not? Manage it through redux? Wrap every component in a HOC which gets the information about the end of subscription? Are there libraries?
I looked into this https://github.com/tdeekens/flopflip but thats a little too much. I don't want a provider such as launch darkly.

I am a little clueless, never did that and thankful for every finger point...

Comment: You can create an `overlay` which spans the whole screen. Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852276/make-div-overlay-entire-page-not-just-viewport

Comment: Why even _render_ the normal UI once you know a subscription is inactive? Render a "renew subscription" link instead.

Comment: @9000 What if there are certain features available, depending on the plan you choose?

Comment: @Stophface: as in `if (subscriptionActive) { <NormalUI/> } else { <SubscriptionEndedUI/> };`?

Answer (score 0):

Just after `render()` function of the component. Use a `boolean` flag to check if the subscription has ended. And just like @9000 recommends, render a `renew-subscription` component if it has ended, otherwise an normal UI could be rendered.