# Getting background image to fill div beyond viewport

Tags: html, css

How can I get the image on the left side of this site to completely fill the div, even when you have to scroll down below the viewport?

http://anjanettetodd.com/

Right now I'm using this code...

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


div.left {
     float: left;
     width: 45%; 
     background-image: url('img/anjanettetodd.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
     }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the height REALLY 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938536/how-to-make-the-height-really-100)

Comment: Are you saying that you want the image to be fixed in place? Even if you scroll? If so, then just add a `position:fixed` to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not provide a link to your website. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: Set the `height: 100vh`, and `position: fixed`

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: fixed;` to fix the left div, where you could scroll down though the right div. So it looks good and the scroll will not show you an empty space