# CSS overlay with height greater than page height & page greater than overlay

Tags: html, css, overlay

I try to create a menu that pops up over the page. The height of the menu is variable and could be greater than the viewport and/or the page content. Here is simplified code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

#overlay {
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;

}

#popup {
  margin: 50px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="popup">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  Page content
</div>
```

When the page content is greater than the viewport height, the user can scroll the page even when the overlay is on the screen:

https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ydmwLo2j/1/

On the other hand, when the menu is greater than the viewport height the user can't scroll to see the bottom of the menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/ydmwLo2j/2/

I already try many stuff with `overflow: scroll;`. But nothing works.

Any solution to solve both issues?

I already read this question, but it does not help: [How to make the height REALLY 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938536/how-to-make-the-height-really-100/1938592#1938592)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add to the overlay:

```
height: 100%;
overflow: auto;
```

Since the overlay cover the entire page, the scroll bar will be apply to the overlay only : https://jsfiddle.net/65na8hy3/

To prevent scrolling the main content, add:

body {
overflow: hidden;
}

Kill two birds with one stone, as you expected.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I expected

Answer (score 1):

I gave `min-height:100vh` and `position:relative` values to `#overlay` id .In html file i put all code in to the `#content` id. I added background color to `#content` and removed `#overlay`'s background color. Changed `#content`'s height to 300vh.

You can control it with codepen: https://codepen.io/yusufdogandev/pen/ZEqWvVe

```css
* {
  margin:0;
}
#overlay {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align:left;
    
}

#popup {
  margin: 50px;
  height:200vh;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  
}

#content {
  height: 300vh;
  background: #4c4c4cb4;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
Page content
<div id="overlay">

  <div id="popup">
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the modal opens, set `overflow: hidden` on the `<body>` element of the page. This will prevent scrolling when the page is taller than the viewport. Add a maximum height to the modal container to make its content scrollable when it is taller than the viewport.

```js
const popupContent = document.querySelector('.js-popup-content');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

document.querySelector('.js-demo-0').addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupContent.style.height = '50vh';
  content.style.height = '200vh';
});

document.querySelector('.js-demo-1').addEventListener('click', () => {
  popupContent.style.height = '200vh';
  content.style.height = '50vh';
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

#overlay {
  min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: center;
    
}

#popup {
  margin: 50px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.demo-buttons {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div id="popup">
    <div class="js-popup-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="demo-buttons">
  <button class="js-demo-0">Short popup, long content</button>
  <button class="js-demo-1">Long popup, short content</button>
</div>

<div id="content">
  Page content
</div>
```